# Why does "orthogonality" matter when using poly(x,degrees=1)?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, contrasts

I think I understand why orthogonality matters when doing regression with polynomial fits (so that the linear and quadratic, cubic, etc... can be evaluated independently). However, I don't understand what orthogonality even means when it comes to doing simply a linear regression. Specifically, in a regression with both continuous (age) and categorical (sex) variables, how I set up my continuous variable in the model will affect all coefficients.

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
agevar=1:60
sexvar <- rep(c("male","female"),each=30)
set.seed(8093)
xvals <- sample(-100:100,60)
m1 <- summary(lm(xvals~sexvar*poly(agevar,1,raw=T))) # uses raw contrasts (i.e. 1:60)
# m1b <- summary(lm(xvals~sexvar*agevar)) # alternative to m1, same result

coef(m1)

                                    Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                      25.13963663 28.0506961  0.8962215 0.3739710
sexvar1                          35.44078606 28.0506961  1.2634548 0.2116605
poly(agevar, 1, raw = T)          0.09955506  0.7997637  0.1244806 0.9013805
sexvar1:poly(agevar, 1, raw = T) -1.26395996  0.7997637 -1.5804168 0.1196438

m2 <- summary(lm(xvals~sexvar*poly(agevar,1,raw=F))) # uses set of contrasts that sum to zero

coef(m2)

                                    Estimate Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                        28.176066   13.85039  2.0343159 0.04666608
sexvar1                            -3.109993   13.85039 -0.2245419 0.82315296
poly(agevar, 1, raw = F)           13.354858  107.28465  0.1244806 0.90138052
sexvar1:poly(agevar, 1, raw = F) -169.554469  107.28465 -1.5804168 0.11964377
```

Any idea on why the result is different and which way is correct? My actual data set uses the same variables, but is much larger with an unequal number of males/females and different sample size at each age.

Comment: I think [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053/what-does-the-r-function-poly-really-do) will help you.

Comment: Thanks @ScouserInTrousers. Great link and saved for future reference, but that addresses mainly how orthogonality is appropriate for polynomials >2. I'm trying to wrap my head around why it seems to still matter when it's just degrees=1... in my mind, orthogonality isn't an issue when you only have one set of contrasts

Comment: In which package can we find the `randn` function?

Comment: ah, my apologies. Didn't realize 'randn' wasn't a default function. It is in the 'pracma' package. Nonetheless, I've changed it to 'sample' to avoid needing additional packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of points here. Your example is not really about polynomial contrasts, but rather about the fact that regression coefficients are not invariant under changes of location and scale. As you point out, the raw first degree polynomial is simply 1:60, and the cooked version is a linear transform, rescaled and centered about 0. Let's call these $y_1$ and $y_2$. Then you have:

$$
xvals =\alpha + \beta_1 Sex + \beta_2 y_1 + \beta_3 (y_2 \times Sex)
$$
and

$$
y_1 = \beta_4 + \beta_5 y_2
$$

If you substitute $y_1$in the first equation with the second equation and collect terms, you will see that the coefficients of Sex, $y_2$ and the interaction term differ from $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$.

$$
xvals = \alpha + (\beta_1 + \beta_3 \beta_4) Sex + \beta_2 \beta_5 y_2 + \beta_3 \beta_5 (y_2 \times Sex)
$$

You will also see from this exercise that if you omit the interaction term from your model, so that $\beta_3=0$, the coefficient of `Sex` remains the same following the transformation.

Note, however, that your p-values remain the same for the linear and interaction terms.

Now back to polynomial contrasts, the options line that you quote from R says that by default, R uses treatment contrasts for unordered categories and polynomial contrasts for ordered categories. An ordered category with 5 levels (think Likert item) adds 4 dummy variables and 4 degrees of freedom to the model. Polynomial contrasts usually make more sense than treatment contrasts in that situation.

With a numeric variable, you can add polynomial terms by adding powers to the model, say `xval ~ Sex + Age + Age^2`, or you could create polynomial contrasts. The coefficients would be different, but the significance tests would remain the same.

Comment: This is great, thanks @Placidia. I was digesting your comment and now understand why the transformation changes the coefficients! The beta represents the slope for each factor in the equation, so when the x-scale (i.e., age) is from -1 to 1, centred on 0, compared to 1 to 60, then of course you'd expect the coefficients to differ. I appreciate the detailed explanation!